# Print Mapbox/Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I want to print a Mapbox Map, that has custom Pins on it.
On Chrome or Safari, there is no problem, because I can just use the window.print command.

The problems I have with Firefox and IE when trying to print:

- Pins show up in the wrong position
- Pins completely disappear

What I also tried:

- Html2Canvas: That did not work, I guess because the tiles have fixed layouts. The canvas you get back only shows the typical grey/white grid "behind" the map
- Static MapBox API: I need the pins numbered higher than 9, and the Mapbox API only offers Pins from 0 to 9.

Do you have any good idea how to solve this problem?
Is there a chance to use the static Mapbox API with custom pins?

Answer (score 2):

That CSS snippet did it:

```
.leaflet-container img { max-width:none!important; }
```

Comment: did what? Can you post some more info on what configuration worked for you? Thanks!